# How can i get user's language as a ISO-639-2 code?

Tags: java, locale

I'd like to get this user's OS language as a ISO-639-2 (3 letter language code). If I query the system properties, I get it as a two letter code:

```
System.getProperty("user.language")
```

Is there a function call in Java which allows me to get the 3 letter language code without having a create a separate mapping table?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I asked too quick. My fault. Anyway, this seems to do it.

```
Locale.getDefault().getISO3Language()
```